# How can I increase display time of ngxtoastr

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to increase display time for ngx-toastr.
I am using toastr.success on the success message from API

```
 this.toastr.success(this.successMessage);
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the [function signature](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/master/src/lib/toastr/toastr.service.ts#L71) is something along the lines

```
success(message?: string, title?: string, override: Partial<IndividualConfig> = {})
```

So I think you could just pass the `override` argument with the [IndividualConfig](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/8d5ea18ecde86f2c98a0eb0154f033e2eee38e97/src/lib/toastr/toastr-config.ts#L13) of `timeOut` to be what you want, so like 10 seconds for example:

```
 this.toastr.success(this.successMessage, null, { timeOut: 10000 }); // 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd argument of the function can be changed to timeOut as an override JSON value.

Is in milliseconds

```
 this.toastr.success(this.successMessage, null, {timeOut: 5000});
```